# Can't get user parameter to work in zabbix 3.4

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-api

I just set up zabbix today on my local machine. I might be missing something trivial but I can't get my user parameter to work in zabbix 3.4

There already seemed to be mysql user parameters in `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d/userparameter_mysql.conf`. I just changed that file to add a custom parameter at the end of the file like so

`UserParameter=mysql.abc,mysql -V`

Restarted the zabbix agent but don't see the parameter making it to zabbix. See the rest of the user parameters defined in that file in zabbix though.

Answer (score 0):

Instruction for mysql database monitoring are: [templates/db/mysql_agent](https://github.com/zabbix/zabbix/tree/master/templates/db/mysql_agent). Don't forget to configure Selinux.

If you are setting up Zabbix today, please do yourself a favor and use the latest version.

Remember, when you upgrade Zabbix, new templates are not imported! If you upgrade Zabbix from 3.4 to 5, you still need to manually import/upgrade the template.